# What does the -1 mean at the end of the docker-compose generated name

Tags: docker-compose

Using docker-compose
version: "3.7"

When not using a `container_name` attribute, with `docker ps` I can see under NAME column that the instance was renamed with the following scheme:

`<project>-<service>-1`

What does the -1 stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a replica number. If the service has several [replicas](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#replicas), the number will be incremented for each replica, for example
docker-compose

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  python-cont:
    build: .
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
```

```
docker compose up -d
[+] Running 4/4
 ⠿ Network params-test_default          Created                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 ⠿ Container params-test-python-cont-3  Started                                                                                                                                                                        0.9s
 ⠿ Container params-test-python-cont-2  Started                                                                                                                                                                        0.8s
 ⠿ Container params-test-python-cont-1  Started
```